# Javascript onSubmit basic form validation

Tags: javascript

Hi I am just curious why the onsubmit function won't respond if the validation function is enclosed inside: (function(){ })();

```
<form id="testform" name="entform" onsubmit="return promptChar()" method="post">
 <input id="input-text" name="entchar" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text" />
 <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<script>
 (function(){

  function promptChar(){
  var field = document.getElementById('input-text').value;

   if(field == "a"){
    alert('hey');
    return false
   }
  }
 })();
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aqqn5u5v/

please also try to test it locally and copy the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline event listeners expects handler function to be under `global-scope` but in your script, handler is in the local scope of `IIFE`

[**`(function(){})();`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)(*`IIFE`*), *executes immediately after it’s created.*[[*Ref*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)]

```js
function promptChar() {
  var field = document.getElementById('input-text').value;
  if (field == "a") {
    alert('hey');
    return false
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="testform" name="entform" onsubmit="return promptChar()" method="post">
  <input id="input-text" name="entchar" type="text" placeholder="Enter Text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

### [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/aqqn5u5v/1/)

Comment: hi thanks for the response. I don't understand it much. I am basically new to javascript, when do I need to use (function(){})(); ? and, is it safe to use it?